# How can I push a row to a table after filtering it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have a table that is populated by an ng-repeat, I have a filter linked to an input to filter the results of the table, and I have another function that will push a new row to the table when a button is clicked. My problem right now is that adding a new row does not work after the filter is used without reloading the page.

I suspect that I need to use $watch to somehow monitor the array of table items, but I just can't quite figure it out.

Please note that I am also using the Angular Material framework and [this](https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table) module for tables.

This is my table HTML:

```
<md-card layout-padding style="width:90%;margin-top:50px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" class="md-whiteframe-5dp">
<div layout="row">
    <div flex="5"></div>
    <md-input-container flex="30">
        <label>Filter</label>
        <input ng-model="filter">
    </md-input-container>
</div>
<md-table-container style="margin-top:-40px;">
    <table md-table>
        <thead md-head md-order="query.name">
            <tr md-row>
                <th md-column></th>
                <th md-column md-order-by="name">Name</th>
                <th md-column md-order-by="position">Position</th>
                <th md-column md-order-by="startDate">Start Date</th>
                <th md-column class="noselect">Shift</th>
                <th md-column class="noselect">Phone</th>
                <th md-column class="noselect">Email</th>
                <th md-column class="noselect">CRM</th>
                <th md-column class="noselect">Xencall</th>
                <th md-column></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody md-body>
            <tr md-row ng-repeat="tableItem in tableItems | orderBy: query.name | filter:filter">
                <td md-cell>
                    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" href="#employee">Files</md-button>
                </td>
                <td md-cell nowrap="nowrap" ng-click="editName($event, tableItem)">{{tableItem.name || "Name"}}</td>
                <td md-cell nowrap="nowrap" ng-click="editPosition($event, tableItem)">{{tableItem.position || "Position"}}</td>
                <td md-cell nowrap="nowrap" ng-click="editStartDate($event, tableItem)">{{tableItem.startDate || "Start Date"}}</td>
                <td md-cell nowrap="nowrap" ng-click="editShift($event, tableItem)">{{tableItem.shift || "Shift"}}</td>
                <td md-cell nowrap="nowrap" ng-click="editPhone($event, tableItem)">{{tableItem.phone || "Phone Number"}}</td>
                <td md-cell nowrap="nowrap" ng-click="editEmail($event, tableItem)">{{tableItem.email || "Email Address"}}</td>
                <td md-cell nowrap="nowrap" ng-click="editCrm($event, tableItem)">{{tableItem.crm || "CRM"}}</td>
                <td md-cell nowrap="nowrap" ng-click="editXencall($event, tableItem)">{{tableItem.xencall || "Xencall"}}</td>
                <td md-cell>
                    <md-button class="md-raised md-accent" ng-click="removeRow($index)">Terminate</md-button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</md-table-container>
```

And this is the controller:

```
employeeMgmt.controller('tableCtrl', function ($scope, $mdEditDialog) {
$scope.tableItems = [
    {
        name: "David Wong"
        , position: "Survey Rep"
        , startDate: "2016-04-20"
        , shift: "11:00 am - 9:00 pm"
        , phone: "(123) 456-7890"
        , email: "dwong@email.com"
        , crm: "dwong"
        , xencall: "dwong"
    }
    , {
        name: "David Wang"
        , position: "Closer"
        , startDate: "2016-04-18"
        , shift: "11:00 am - 9:00 pm"
        , phone: "(123) 456-7890"
        , email: "dwong@email.com"
        , crm: "dwong"
        , xencall: "dwong"
    }
    , {
        name: "David Weng"
        , position: "Jr Broker"
        , startDate: "2016-04-22"
        , shift: "11:00 am - 9:00 pm"
        , phone: "(123) 456-7890"
        , email: "dwong@email.com"
        , crm: "dwong"
        , xencall: "dwong"
    }
    , {
        name: "David Wung"
        , position: "Survey Rep"
        , startDate: "2016-04-19"
        , shift: "11:00 am - 9:00 pm"
        , phone: "(123) 456-7890"
        , email: "dwong@email.com"
        , crm: "dwong"
        , xencall: "dwong"
    }
    , {
        name: "David Wyng"
        , position: "Closer"
        , startDate: "2016-04-21"
        , shift: "11:00 am - 9:00 pm"
        , phone: "(123) 456-7890"
        , email: "dwong@email.com"
        , crm: "dwong"
        , xencall: "dwong"
    }
    , {
        name: "David Wing"
        , position: "Survey Rep"
        , startDate: "2016-04-20"
        , shift: "11:00 am - 9:00 pm"
        , phone: "(123) 456-7890"
        , email: "dwong@email.com"
        , crm: "dwong"
        , xencall: "dwong"
    }
];
$scope.query = {
    order: 'name'
};
$scope.addRow = function () {
    var tableItem = {
        name: $scope.name
        , position: $scope.position
        , startDate: $scope.startDate
        , shift: $scope.shift
        , phone: $scope.phone
        , email: $scope.email
        , crm: $scope.crm
        , xencall: $scope.xencall
    };
    $scope.tableItems.push(tableItem);
};
$scope.removeRow = function (index) {
    $scope.tableItems.splice(index, 1);
};
});
```

Comment: Hi Matt, welcome to StackOverflow. That's a lot of code to expect people who might be able to help you to read through. You'll likely get a better response if you slim down your code to the bare essentials required for the question.

Comment: @Erresen I have removed the code for the the edit dialogs. Only the most relevant code remains.

Comment: I made a Plunker from the Angular Filter example and it displays just fine when adding rows.  It even displays while the filter is applied, if it matches the filter.  https://plnkr.co/edit/XB6hYWc7fvrYk65sx7RY?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Because you're allowing the adding of blank rows, you'll need to add `track by $index`.

ng-repeat="tableItem in tableItems | filter: filter track by $index"

You're trying to add duplicate people to your array and it's breaking your table.  Here's a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/HpZrufhS5jzSi3EpYHPk?p=preview

You need to add `angular.equals` check before adding to the array.

```
$scope.addRow = function(emp) {

  //check for duplicates
  for(var i = 0; i < $scope.tableItems.length; ++i) {
    if(angular.equals($scope.tableItems[i], emp)) {
      return; //break if found
    }
  }

  //go ahead and add
  $scope.tableItems.push(emp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is working, but now I can only add one row. I need to be able to add multiple blank rows.

Also, I'm afraid that I don't really understand what it is doing now. I need to review vanilla javascript (I don't remember how for loops work). So I'm not sure what "emp" means.

Comment: Why do you need to add blank rows?  `emp` is simply an object you pass in.

Comment: The idea is that that a new row would be added, the table cells for that row would be edited, then another row added, cells edited, and so on. As it is now, after adding and editing a row, the addRow button no longer functions.

Comment: Then you need to remove the logic check (bear in mind that users can still add duplicate employees--so you need to validate this before hitting the API and saving to server.)  Please see working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/HpZrufhS5jzSi3EpYHPk?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you clean the filter input. Maybe the filter input has a value and the new item doesn't match filter criteria